# C optimzation techniques

Tags: c, performance, function, optimization

I am looking for the fastest optimization from the below function w/o getting into assembly because it seems to be the bottle neck of my application.  Keep in mind that the following function is already declared inline.

definitions: P = 10 and N = 240

```
void autocorrelation( int32_t *data , float *r){
    for ( int m=0 ; m < P+1 ; m++)
    {
        register float temp = 0;
        for ( int n=0 ; n<N-m ; n++)
        {
            temp += (float)(data[n])*(float)(data[n+m]);
        }
        r[m] = temp;
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

assembly:

```
temp += (float)(data[n])*(float)(data[n+m]);
800063A8  lddsp R8, SP[0x0]      
800063AA  add R1, R2, R8<<0      
800063AE  ld.w R12, R1[R7<<0]        
800063B2  mcall 0x80006f58       
800063B6  mov R4, R12        
800063B8  ld.w R12, R2[R7<<0]        
800063BC  mcall 0x80006f58       
800063C0  mov R11, R12       
800063C2  mov R12, R4        
800063C4  mcall 0x80006f5c       
800063C8  mov R11, R12       
800063CA  mov R12, R5        
800063CC  mcall 0x80006f60       
800063D0  mov R5, R12        
for ( int n=0 ; n<N-m ; n++)
800063D2  sub R6, -1         
800063D4  sub R7, -4         
800063D6  cp.w R6, R3        
800063D8  brne 0x800063ae        
r[m] = temp;
800063DA  ld.w R10, PC[2954]         
800063DE  lddsp R9, SP[0x0]      
800063E0  st.w R10[R9<<0], R5        
800063E4  sub R0, 1      
800063E6  sub R9, -4         
800063E8  stdsp SP[0x0], R9      
for ( int m=0 ; m < P+1 ; m++)
800063EA  cp.w R0, 229       
800063EE  breq 0x800063fc        
800063F0  mov R3, R0         
for ( int n=0 ; n<N-m ; n++)
800063F2  cp.w R0, 0         
800063F4  brgt 0x800063a2        
800063F8  mov R5, 0      
800063FA  rjmp 0x800063da
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

So I changed the code to:

```
void autocorrelation( float *data , float *r){
    for ( int m=0 ; m < P+1 ; m++)
    {
        register float temp = 0;
        for ( int n=0 ; n<N-m ; n++)
        {
            temp += data[n]*data[n+m];
        }
        r[m] = temp;
    }
}
```

and cut the time by a third (each tick is 1/16000Hz) - 
originally - 108 ticks
now        - 70 ticks

new assembly:

```
temp += data[n]*data[n+m];
800063C2  add R2, R3, R0<<0      
800063C6  ld.w R11, R3[R7<<0]        
800063CA  ld.w R12, R2[R7<<0]        
800063CE  mcall 0x80006f68       
800063D2  mov R11, R12       
800063D4  mov R12, R5        
800063D6  mcall 0x80006f6c       
800063DA  mov R5, R12        
for ( int n=0 ; n<N-m ; n++)
800063DC  sub R6, -1         
800063DE  sub R7, -4         
800063E0  cp.w R6, R4        
800063E2  brne 0x800063c6        
r[m] = temp;
800063E4  ld.w R9, PC[2960]      
800063E8  st.w R9[R0<<0], R5         
800063EC  sub R1, 1      
800063EE  sub R0, -4         
for ( int m=0 ; m < P+1 ; m++)
800063F0  cp.w R1, 229       
800063F4  breq 0x80006402        
800063F6  mov R4, R1         
for ( int n=0 ; n<N-m ; n++)
800063F8  cp.w R1, 0         
800063FA  brgt 0x800063bc        
800063FE  mov R5, 0      
80006400  rjmp 0x800063e4
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
FINAL Final Solution: (changed again)

I combined the marked solution and unwound the loop with an application I wrote and stayed in 64bits until the end, performance increase from 60ticks to 20ticks from last.  Over 6 functions with the same tweaks, I was able to pull from the very beginning of what seemed to be optimized code at 250 ticks down to 50 ticks where my ping pong buffers needed everything to get done within 160 ticks, so I have some head room:

```
void fastAutocorrelation( int64_t *data , float *r){

int64_t *temp;
int64_t *datan = data;
int64_t *datanm = data;

*temp = (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*r++ = (float)(*temp)/int64ToFloat;

datan = data;
datanm = data + 1;
*temp = (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
*temp += (*datan++)*(*datanm++);
...
```

Comment: What optimizations have you tried so far that have failed?

Comment: Inlining the function won't do anything.  Those float conversions will be costing you.  What is the range of the values in `data`?  Have you output the function's assembly to see what your compiler has done with those repeated calculations for `N-m` and `n+m`?

Comment: I am currently changing the code so that data coming in is 'float' so I can eliminate recasting 2400+ times . . . outside of that, not much.  I was hoping for some advice on pointer tricks?  or anything else that may help (excluding compiler optimizations past O1, algorithm gets messed up after that for some reason)

Comment: data will be maximum of 255*128*128 = 4177920 and this is a 32 bit system

Comment: please see above for code changes and results, thanks! any ideas with the pointers?

Comment: In the worst possible case, that data range will still fit easily in a 64-bit integer after all your multiplications.  You might want to try benchmarking a 64-bit integer versus `float` versus `double`.

Comment: sounds good Paddy, I will test it out.  I was wondering if there was a program out there that would help me unwind the for loop without having me go through it one by one?  Or should I write an application to do that . . . could be cool

Comment: if I unwind it I think I can reduce it down to 1 tick with 2400 additional lines of code . . . I am only using 13% of the memory . . . what do you guys think

Comment: Have you thought about computing the autocorrelation through the use of FFT and IFFT? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Efficient_computation - I'm not sure at what N this would become more efficient than the brute force method.

Comment: I am eventually getting to 15 LPC coefficients through linear prediction.  In the macro scheme, this is the fastest route when compared to FFT's by far

Comment: This could probably be optimized using FMA instructions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set).

Comment: what architecture are you working on?

Comment: It looks like your latest code is wrong -- `temp` should not be a pointer.

Comment: are you saying that it isn't equivalent?  Because I tested it.  Initialized as pointer and then filling the contents of what it is pointing to.  It is more there to hint to the compiler what I want it to do.  Could you elaborate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've cut back a bit by removing the casts.  If you're after pointer tricks, here's one to try.  Depending on your compiler, your mileage will vary:

```
void autocorrelation( float *restrict data, float *restrict r)
{
    float *data_end = data + N;

    for ( int m=0 ; m < P+1 ; m++)
    {
        float temp = 0;

        for( float *data_n = data, *data_nm = data + m;
             data_nm != data_end;
             data_n++, data_nm++ )
        {
            temp += *data_n * *data_nm;
        }

        r[m] = temp;
    }
}
```

I added in the `restrict` keyword so the compiler knows `data` and `r` do not overlap or point to the same thing.

Comment: thanks Paddy, I built my solution off of your comments (see my last edited body paragraph above)

Comment: Goodness me, that's an awful lot of unwinding.  You could have at least done it in chunks (as with [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)).  Did you try using 64-bit integers for the data source and accumulator?  That way you just convert to float at the end, and could be a lot faster.  Assuming that your processor multiplies and adds floats slower than 64-bit integers.  That might not be the case.  Worth benchmarking though.

Comment: Yea that was the last thing I did, I have been optimizing all of my functions at the same time (unwinding them, etc.) and the second I switched over to 64bits from floats (my arch is 32 bit with floating point hardware) the function above dropped to 20 ticks*(1/16000Hz) ~ 1.25ms.  I switched back over to floats at the: *r++ = (float)(temp)/268435456;  // where the 268435456 is from int multiples along the way to keep resolution (128*128) which is then squared in this function (sum of squares)

Answer (score 3):

Observe that your processor does not have any floating point capabilities; the floating point operations are being emulated in software. This means that the bottleneck is not the loop control (which the compiler is already doing a good job of strength-reducing). The bottleneck is the floating point emulator.

Given that your processor does not have native floating point, it's likely that it also does not have a large L1 cache. Changing the order of the loop controls may improve data locality. The original code makes 10 sweeps across a 240-element array, which is poor locality. Better would be to make one sweep across the array, studying 10 items at a time.

```
void autocorrelation( int32_t *data , float *r){
  int m, n;
  for (m = 0; m < P + 1; m++) r[m] = 0.0f;
  for (n = 0; n < N; n++) {
    int limit = min(P + 1, N - n);
    for (m = 0; m < limit; m++) {
      r[m] += data[n] * data[n+m];
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that conversion to pointers won't help, because the original code was already optimized by the compiler to use pointers.)

Comment: One suspects that doing one floating-point conversion at the end might be even better.

Comment: @BenVoigt Certainly if we can avoid floating point, the code would run significantly faster. But I was sort of assuming that floating point was required by the problem scenario. (It looks like some sort of signal processing.)

Comment: Well, integer multiplication and addition are both exact, and you're already depending on the multiplication to not overflow.  So one could presumably convert to floating point after all the additions, not before.

Comment: @BenVoigt But if the original values have fractions or are greater than 2^32, integers won't work.

Comment: When `int32_t* data`, the argument type in the question, starts carrying fractional information, I'll have to turn in my C++ hat.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, copy-paste error on my part. I failed to notice that there are two versions of the original function, one where `data` is `int32_t*` and another where it is `float*`. I thought it was always `float*`. If it is `int32_t` then yes, work in integers if you know that the result will not overflow an int.

Comment: @BenVoigt I switched the arithmetic to keep everything in 64bits and then switched to float and divided out 11 times in the unrolled loop.  It cut the time significantly from the previous performance update (now all of my functions combined (6 other functions just like this) can be processed in 55 ticks - 3ms)

Comment: there is just one thing hidden in the math that numbers multiplied below 0 get smaller but in int they do not (makes Hamming wave processing a little sketchy)

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling like some adventurous experimentation you might try Intel's ICC compiler (was that x86 assembler?). With the right command line switches that will automatically parallelise your for loops by using separate threads for each loop iterations. However the loops do need to be fairly meaty for the overhead of the threads to be worthwhile.

Another approach is to get down and dirty with SSE and AVX. Better still I think the latest Intel x86s have a multiply/add instruction, which is what is needed for correlations, FFTs, etc. That way you would be vectorising your code, and several operations would be happening per clock cycle (beyond what the ordinary CPU pipeline can achieve). Effectively there are some additional 'functions' that map directly onto SSE/AVX opcodes, allowing them to be easily used in C code. The compiler does have to know about these (Intel's one certainly does), otherwise you're putting in your own online assembler. You also then have the problem of dealing with different versions of CPUs at runtime; not every PC has the latest Intel chip.

Or you could be really lazy like I am and use a library of pre-optimised routines like Intel's IPP/MKL. It, like ICC, costs money, but it can be well worthwhile if speed = big money in your project.

Comment: A good answer for platforms that include an x86 processor. Unfortunately, the OP's code is not for the x86 (registers are named, rather than numbered. Other mnemonics indicate a different platform too) Anyway, gets my vote.

Comment: I did wonder if it was x86! However, the general theme holds true on other platforms. There's VSIPL that is available on a variety of CPUS, does the same job as Intel's IPP/MKL. Quite a lot of CPUs have a SIMD extension like SSE, and clever compilers can generally be found. Good luck OP

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

1) Advancing pointers instead of indexing the `r` array? (Like @paddy did for `data_n` and `data_m`). E.g. `*(r++) = temp` instead of `r[m] = temp`

2) Loop unrolling. Your compiler obviously does not do this, and this will be a big speed gain for the internal loop, for example. Specifically, have a look at http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/Duff's_device for neat loop unrolling.

3) Take loop unrolling to the extreme! (Maybe not pretty, I know, but cool nonetheless): you *know* the values of `N` and `P`: you can just completely unroll the loop, and write all the code (albeit long) without any branches. Depending on your architecture (enough prefetch pipeline, coupled with dumb branch prediction), this may very well increase speed. You could even write a small utility that *generates* the complete unrolled loop for you, and include the generated code in your `.c` file. Or just use macros and metaprogramming.

Comment: If you look at the original assembly, you'll see that the compiler already reduced the array index operation to pointers. `R7` is the relative pointer. Also, most of the work is in the floating point functions, not the loop control. Unrolling will not help much and will probably hurt icache.

Comment: It's not a question of 'probably', you beed to test and see. But I agree it may be slower, and even wrote that results are arch. dependent.

Comment: yea you are right about a small increase in performance after unrolling but it was enough to keep the floats (which helps keep the spectral density results understandable). later stages are in floats (until the very end) so it was going to have to cast types somewhere.